# Wrong initial values of useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I've found something that breaks my mind a little. I have a code:

```
// those constanst just for test needs
// sd === '2021-02-15'
const sd = moment(reservation.StartDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
// ed === '2021-03-15'
const ed = moment(reservation.EndDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

const [dateArr, setDate] = useState<string[]>([sd, ed]);    

const updateStartDate = (d: string) => {
    const nDateArr = [d, dateArr[1]]
    setDate(nDateArr);
}
const updateEndDate = (d: string) => {
    const nDateArr = [dateArr[0], d]
    setDate(nDateArr);
}
```

As I described in comment `sd === '2021-02-15'` and `ed === '2021-03-15'`, so I expect that `dateArr === ['2021-02-15','2021-03-15']`. But in fact `dateArr === ['2021-02-15','2021-02-15']` ! Why?!

I've change code a little:

```
// those constanst just for test needs
// sd === '2021-02-15'
const sd = moment(reservation.StartDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
// ed === '2021-03-15'
const ed = moment(reservation.EndDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

const [dateArr, setDate] = useState<string[]>([sd, '2021-03-15']);    

const updateStartDate = (d: string) => {
    const nDateArr = [d, dateArr[1]]
    setDate(nDateArr);
}
const updateEndDate = (d: string) => {
    const nDateArr = [dateArr[0], d]
    setDate(nDateArr);
}
```

And it works! `dateArr === ['2021-02-15','2021-03-15']` !

Could someone explain to me the difference of direct string input and using a variable for `useState`?

Comment: There is no difference from React's perspective as clearly the initial state has valid strings. My guess is that `reservation.StartDate` is resolving undefined, or some variation that causes an invalid MomentJS datetime object, and so the MomentJS datetime object reverts to the underlying JS Date object. Have you tested that `moment(reservation.StartDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")` generates the value you expect ***when*** you expect it? What and where does this `reservation` object come from?

Comment: @DrewReese but `useState` initialize with `sd` and `ed` variables, and both of them has values at the moment of initialization.

Comment: Right, which are both valid date strings. State was correctly initialized. I think your question should ***actually*** be, "why are the dates being used for the initial state value incorrect?" They both are, IMO, suspiciously today's date.

Comment: Keep in mind that `moment.js` objects are mutable. Meaning that if you'd change the main object, you're changing all references to this object too. If you'd pass a `moment.js` that you have in your React state to a function, and change stuff there - the state object will be changed too. I'd recommend cloning the moment objects if you're working with state too.